# Neo4j efficiency issue: Cypher query runs forever

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I have a `Neo4j` database of size ~ `70Gb`. It has `8` datasets that are of the same structure, just different nodes. A simple Cypher query presented below that retrieves some data from one dataset takes forever to run. There are not so many nodes in the dataset, just several thousands. Here is the query:

```
MATCH (c:Cell)-[ex:EXPRESSES]->(g:Gene)
WHERE c.DATASET = "cd1_e165" AND g.geneName = "1010001B22Rik" 
RETURN c.tsneX, c.tsneY, ex.expr, c.cellId
```

There is huge amount of `:EXPRESSES` relationships in total, but if we limit only to the `c.DATASET` I am sure it should run way faster. Maybe the issue is somehow related to the fact that I am having `c.DATASET` property in each `:Cell`, and not having it as a kind of index. What could be done to speed up the query?

Comment: Try putting the dataset= ... into the Match and create an index for the property. Same with geneName.

Comment: Definitely add the relevant indexes per Yoshi's comment. Also, can you PROFILE your query and add the query plan to your question (after expanding all elements of the plan)?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use the indexes on both properties.

```
 CREATE INDEX ON :Cell(DATASET);
 CREATE INDEX ON :Gene(geneName);
```

Next I would rewrite the query like this (not sure whether this will help but this makes more sense to me and cypher behaves often just like you would expect it to do and in that case it seems rather clear that it should use the indexes and not start searching for all possible paths):

```
MATCH (c:Cell{DATASET:'cd1_e165'})-[ex:EXPRESSES]->(g:Gene{geneName:'1010001B22Rik'})
RETURN c.tsneX, c.tsneY, ex.expr, c.cellId
```

As InverseFalcon mentioned: `PROFILE` and `EXPLAIN`can always help you understanding what your query does and whether it fits your expectation. Take a look at  [at the docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/).

Comment: Maybe it sped up the database but I do not see a significant difference. Still running forever...

Comment: Please share the query plan